# C++ debug assertion error with std::cin >> char

Tags: c++, console-application, stdout, stdin

**Background**:
The problem/code shown here is part of a larger program I am trying to create (I was told to trim it down). The purpose (of this section) is to be able to receive std::cin input and (when it works) feed it into the function: srcdsControl->WriteText(string(chr)); This function is part of the larger program, which I have not created myself.

I'm trying to redirect input and output from a C++ console application to a Python script (which I have written, and which works). When I type into the console window, it receives the input fine. However, when I send input to the program's stdin from python (in the format 'command\r\n'), it triggers the following error:

[image: C++ Debug Assertion Failed error]

I've tried with both of the following programs and they give exactly the same error.

My C++ code (test 1):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        char chr[2];
        chr[1] = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            if (std::cin >> std::noskipws >> chr[0])
            {
                if (chr[0] == '\r')
                    std::cout << "\r";
                //srcdsControl->WriteText(string(chr));
                std::cout << std::string(chr) << "\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // Ignore exception and just stop the thread.
    }
}
```

My C++ code (test 2):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        char chr[2];
        chr[1] = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            std::string s = "";
            if (std::getline(std::cin, s))
            {
                for (char& ch : s) {
                    chr[0] = ch;
                    if (chr[0] == '\r')
                        std::cout << "\r";
                    //srcdsControl->WriteText(std::string(chr));
                    std::cout << std::string(chr) << "\r\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // Ignore exception and just stop the thread.
    }
}
```

**Note**: I am not a C++ developer and my knowledge of C++ is very limited. I need a specific/simple answer.

**My question**: How do I prevent this error and ensure that the input is properly received? I am happy to use a completely different method to receive the input if needed, but would need a specific demonstration of it.

Comment: Consider using `std::getline` to read the data since you appear to be looking for full lines. '\r' is only half of the end of line marker in windows. See the little note at the bottom of the dialogue, "Press Retry to debug the application" and take advantage of the opportunity

Comment: *How do I prevent this error* -- Before putting your C++ code in a larger program, you could have written a very small `main` program with just those lines to see how it behaves.  There is no need to introduce Python, threading, or calling `WriteText` to do this testing to see how C++ streams will work.  That would have been considered a [mcve] instead of code snippets.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have now edited the post to just show a small `main` program.

Comment: @user4581301 I tried to debug it but the exception came from a separate code file and I have too little experience in Visual Studio/C++ to understand any useful information that may have provided.

Comment: There are several problems in your program. (1) It doesn't try to process EOF correctly (no, try-catch won't do). (2) It does try to process `\r` which it most probably shouldn't (the runtime library translates `\r\n` sequences for you).  (3) It looks like the program tries to insert a newline after each character. If this is its purpose in life, then there are simpler and more efficient methods of doing this that don't require writing any code.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to fix my own problem.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        char chr[2];
        chr[1] = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            char c;
            if (std::cin >> std::noskipws >> c)
            {
                chr[0] = c;
                if (chr[0] == '\r')
                    std::cout << "\r";
                //srcdsControl->WriteText(string(chr));
                std::cout << std::string(chr) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // Ignore exception and just stop the thread.
    }
}
```

This code seems to do what I want without giving the error. If anyone can explain why this works and the previous code didn't that would be interesting to know.